# Extra space between fractions

Tags: spacing, fractions

I have heavy fractions in my LaTeX equations.

When there are 2 or more consecutive fractions in a row (i.e. I evaluate a product), they are too close to each other.

Is there any way to add an extra space between fractions in LaTeX mathmode?

To be more precise, I have the following function containing a big fraction:

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}[1]{
    \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{#1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\zeta(#1)}
}
```

I am tired of adding an extra space between them:
`$ \myfrac{1} \, \myfrac{2} $` instead of `$ \myfrac{1} \myfrac{2} $`.

I thought of adding an invisible symbol `\i`
(in the beginning and end of my custom function)
such that `\i` is ignored and `\i\i` works as `\,`.

Another approach is to tune spacing around any fractions, but I failed to find anything related to user-defined spaces between concrete objects.

Here is my code:

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}[1]{
    \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{#1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\zeta(#1)}
}

\begin{document}

Here everything works good:
\begin{equation*}
    a = 4 + \myfrac{1} < 5.
\end{equation*}

However, here the space between the fractions is too small:
\begin{equation*}
    b = 7 + \myfrac{1} \myfrac{2} < 5,
\end{equation*}
so I have to add an extra space:
\begin{equation*}
    b = 7 + \myfrac{1} \; \myfrac{2} < 5.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: the following output]

Just adding `\,` to the end of custom function seems not working, as then the space between `\myfrac{1}` and other operators (i.e., `=`) is larger than expected.

Comment: You might look at the code used by tabular to process `||` or `\hline\hline`.  It treats two consecutive `\hlines` in a totally different way from normal.  The code is also very complicated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: Not that it helps you, but it could be comforting (and interesting to know): In the newer engine luametatex fraction is its own atom class (like ordinary, binary, relation, ...), so to solve your problem, one could (locally) increase the fraction-fraction space.

Answer (score 7):

You can check whether another `\myfrac` follows and, in this case, add `\;`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfrac}[1]{%
  \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{#1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\zeta(#1)}%
  \@ifnextchar\myfrac{\;}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    a = 4 + \myfrac{1} < 5.
\\
    b = 7 + \myfrac{1} \myfrac{2} < 5.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfrac}{m}
 {
  \dfrac{\int\limits\sb{0}\sp{#1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\zeta(#1)}
  \peek_remove_spaces:n { \peek_meaning:NT \myfrac {\;} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    a = 4 + \myfrac{1} < 5.
\\
    b = 7 + \myfrac{1} \myfrac{2} < 5.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

You might consider a different syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \oleg_zetafrac:n
 {
  \dfrac{\int\limits\sb{0}\sp{#1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\zeta(#1)}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \oleg_zetafrac:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand{\zetafrac}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \oleg_zetafrac:V \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \; \oleg_zetafrac:n { ##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    a = 4 + \zetafrac{1} < 5.
\\
    b = 7 + \zetafrac{1;2} < 5.
\\
    c = 11 + \zetafrac{1;2;3} < 5.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, not that complicated after all.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I need! Thanks!!