# Extra space in fractions

Tags: math-mode, fractions

What is the civilized way to modify `\frac` so that there is a little horizontal padding — using CSS terms — so as to avoid things like

[image]

which looks like it is going to tip over? One can (use a command to) use instead `\frac{\;t\;}{\;s\;}`, which gives the less stress-inducing

[image]

I wonder if there is some subtlety to be taken into account (and why `\frac` does not do this…)

Comment: I would not recommend this as a general solution. Change `t` to `\lambda` and you will see the problem and to be honest it gives me no stress seeing it as was designed and I have been texing now for almost 40 years.

Comment: The screenshots you posted do not appear to be using the default (Computer Modern) font. Please let us which math font package you employ.

Comment: Indeed, that's MnSymbol/MinionPro in the screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra space between fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646751/extra-space-between-fractions)

Comment: @Sebastiano, that is a completely different question, so no.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok. I have retract the vote of closure.

Answer (score 6):

You do not mention what macro package you are using, so I take the freedom of adding a possible way in ConTeXt.

```
\startTEXpage[offset=1DK]
\dm{\frac{t}{s}}

\dm{\frac[margin=.5ex]{t}{s}}

\setupmathfraction
  [margin=2ex]

\dm{\frac{t}{s}}
\stopTEXpage
```

Result:

[image: fractions of different widths]

Answer (score 3):

Not that I think this might be a good idea, but here a couple of ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalfrac}{\frac}
\renewcommand*{\frac}[3][3]{\originalfrac{\mkern#1mu#2\mkern#1mu}{\mkern#1mu#3\mkern#1mu}}
% or
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand*{\frac}[3][3]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\mkern#1mu#2\mkern#1mu}{\mkern#1mu#3\mkern#1mu}}

\begin{document}

\[
\originalfrac{\lambda}{2} = \frac{\lambda}{2} = \frac[5]{\lambda}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]